# dpdk-testpmd panic with "RTE_RING tailq is already registered"

Tags: dpdk, dpdk-pmd

I'm tring to run dpdk's example ethtools using dpdk-19.11.14 on ubuntu 22.04.

I got following errno:

```
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: RTE_RING tailq is already registered
PANIC in tailqinitfn_rte_ring_tailq():
Cannot initialize tailq: RTE_RING
20: [dpdk-testpmd(_start+0x25) [0x5589bb902cf5]]
19: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f714ed02e40]]
18: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f714ed02d90]]
17: [dpdk-testpmd(main+0x78) [0x5589bb837d58]]
16: [dpdk-testpmd(rte_eal_init+0x65e) [0x5589bba5d65e]]
15: [dpdk-testpmd(+0x1187a1) [0x5589bb6ff7a1]]
14: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(dlopen+0x48) [0x7f714ed69748]]
13: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x901ae) [0x7f714ed691ae]]
12: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_error+0x33) [0x7f714ee4dcf3]]
11: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_exception+0x88) [0x7f714ee4dc28]]
10: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x906bc) [0x7f714ed696bc]]
9: [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xe34e) [0x7f714f01934e]]
8: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_exception+0x88) [0x7f714ee4dc28]]
7: [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0xdff6) [0x7f714f018ff6]]
6: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_exception+0xe5) [0x7f714ee4dc85]]
5: [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x6568) [0x7f714f011568]]
4: [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x647e) [0x7f714f01147e]]
3: [/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_ring.so.20.0(+0x1303) [0x7f714eb99303]]
2: [dpdk-testpmd(__rte_panic+0xcd) [0x5589bb7017ef]]
1: [dpdk-testpmd(rte_dump_stack+0x32) [0x5589bba53b72]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Before that example, I had test the helloworld.
Fowlling is result of helloworld.

```
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:01.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:05.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:100f net_e1000_em
EAL:   0000:02:05.0 VFIO group is not viable! Not all devices in IOMMU group bound to VFIO or unbound
EAL: Requested device 0000:02:05.0 cannot be used
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 3
hello from core 0
```

And this error also occured when i run dpdk-testpmd.

I had search a lot similar errno info in Bing, but there's no solution that i want.

One solution is to make static link  librte_*.a to librte_*.so, but I can't understand that.

[tailq is already registered](https://www.programmerall.com/article/16572267017/).

I want to know why this errono occured, and how can fix it.

Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 0):

The dpdk library has been installed on your system-wide and the linker is duplicating the link causing the constructor to run repeatedly.
Solution:

1. Uninstall the system-wide dpdk lib.
2. Run the system-wide testpmd.